# Configure ports in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search . In elastic search

```
  Https ports ranges from 9200-9300 and tcp ports ranges from 9300 to 9400.
  What if i use all  these ports ranges from 9200 to 9400. 
  Will it take new port or throws error.Methodology used to Tcp port calculation?.
  Pls provide me an example.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the case as you don't want to run 100 nodes on a single machine.

So I don't really understand what is exactly your concern here.

That said, if you want to change port, have a look at `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Have a look at:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#_tcp_transport
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: So i cant run more than 100 nodes in single server, though i ve enough resources?   and TCP port calculation methodology ?

Comment: It's a bad practice. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: To be clear, you can run more than 100 nodes on the same machine but I would not do that.

Comment: i don't do that.For understanding purpose only asked.